# Is there any reason I can't hold on to onCreateView's LayoutInflater?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I realize that in situations like this, the idiom is to pass a `Context` to the `CustomAdapter` constructor, and with it create a `LayoutInflater`. But I'm wondering nonetheless whether there is anything wrong with the code below.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      this.inflater = inflater;

      MyLayout layout = (MyLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout);
      SomeAdapterView adapterView  = (SomeAdapterView) layout.findViewById(R.id.adapterView);
      CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(inflater);
      adapterView.setAdapter(adapter);

      return layout;
   }   


   private class CustomAdapter extends WhateverAdapter {
      LayoutInflater inflater;

      public CustomAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
         this.inflater = inflater;
      }   

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         return this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.item);
      }   
   }   

}
```

Comment: What is `viewAt(int)` supposed to do? The usual method for an adapter is `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`.

Comment: Edited. More to come later...

Comment: Per my answer--there's a big performance hit if you inflate a new view for every item in your adapter. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this instead of using the usual approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't see where `inflater` is a field of `MyFragment`, so that's a problem.

Second, I would recommend against keeping a reference to an inflater. It's cheap enough to obtain an inflater with:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

(assuming you have access to a `context` somewhere.) Also, I don't know what kind of adapter has a method `viewAt(int)`. The [usual signature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    . . .
}
```

For performance reasons, you should definitely not inflate a new view on every call to this method. Instead you should check whether the `convertView` argument is already a view of the expected type and only inflate a new view if it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it Global variable. Try this

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      this.inflater = inflater;
      layoutInflater = inflater;

      MyLayout layout = (MyLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout);
      SomeAdapterView adapterView  = (SomeAdapterView) layout.findViewById(R.id.adapterView);
      CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(inflater);
      adapterView.setAdapter(adapter);

      return layout;
   } 
   ...
}
```

Now use `layoutInflater` anywhere in other methods.